# I have a puzzle and a solution... it's the method I'm after

Tags: mathematics, cipher, puzzle-identification, reverse-puzzling

The cipher message is:

J B A Z R X K Z N

T W K O Y E Z

The answer is:

T O N G L A N D

B R I D G E

How did I (or more accurately my father) arrive at the answer?

Comment: First thing I noticed is ROT13(2 zber yrggref va pvcuregrkg guna va cynvagrkg. Guvf zrnaf ab punapr vg'f Pnrfne fuvsg be vgf znal inevnagf (yvxr Ivtrarer), fvapr nyy gubfr pvcuref qba'g punatr grkg yratgu). Otherwise, I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: Is the mathematics tag an independent clue?

Comment: @Hakdo I thought perhaps that might be because the method involves the intervals between successive letters but I didn't find anything interesting.

Comment: I'd like to add either [reverse-puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-puzzling) or [puzzle-identification](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-identification) to this. @Nixy Do you know the answer to your own question?

Comment: Hi there, I would like to add a bit of a back story to my question. I was chatting to my husband the other day and a story he told me reminded me of a story from my past. I couldn't quite remember the details so my parents filled me in.... About 30 years ago, my Dad was trying to raise money for a local squash court and inspired by the book Masquerade decided to set a treasure hunt where people who entered had to solve 10 clues which were all locations and then using those 10 locations a final clue was generated with a final location where a crate of whisky was hidden. No one ever won!

Comment: The last clue was never solved. Apparently over the years various people contacted my father for further help and my dad even send a further clue out to someone in the same code to see if that would help, but it didn't. Apparently, even the army was asked about it! My dad just gave me the answer that was long sought after and asked me if I could work out how it was done. I couldn't and so joined stack exchange after googling about codes for a couple of hours. I tagged it the way I did simply because I didn't know better, sorry! I also don't know the answer, but if you can explain it to me...

Comment: I will report back.... and share any whisky if necessary!@IanMacDonald @WAF

Comment: Treasure hunt for a case of whisky organised in the 1980s by a squash club in Kirkcudbright -- is this related to [this treasure hunt here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/7929/whisky-treasure-hunt-cryptogram-which-refers-to-a-place-in-scotland)?

Comment: OMG... this has totally blown my mind.... and I guess my dad is going to kill me!!!!

Comment: Ok, firstly I feel bad, because after close to 40 years of hunting in earnest for this clue, the idiot daughter just spoiled it. But secondly, wow the internet just bit me on the bum!

Comment: I just looked at the original puzzle and my clue doesn't feature on it, so I am not sure how it fits into the real story. I will ask my dad tomorrow. It's probably a red herring, he knew I wasn't to be trusted!

Comment: Is the crate of whisky still buried under tongland bridge?

Comment: @ImongMama I think tongland bridge might be a false friend... my brother remembers differently. In any case it wasn't the final answer just the last clue which led to the final answer.

Comment: So it seems that the puzzle I left was just in the style of the real clue. Courtesy of the old post link by @MOehm my dad (who was very surprised and amused by his quizes online success after 40 years) now has the original quiz and is seeing if he can still solve it himself!

Answer (score 5):

Method:

> The method is a sliding-alphabet cipher similar to Vigenere, or more precisely, Quagmire 2. As @Evargalo notes, the first letter of each word is likely to be a key. Write the two substitutions below a standard alphabet as if solving a polyalphabetic system, with the key letters outside the table to the left:
>
> ```
>   tongland    bridge
> J BAZRXKZN  T WKOYEZ
>
>
>   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
> J K  N  R    X ZA    B
> T  W YZ E O        K
> ```

> There are a few possibilities for the type of system. A plain Vigenere with standard alphabets is excluded immediately. A Quagmire 3 (an unknown alphabet sliding against itself) is excluded by finding the proportion `E:g::K:r` between the T line and plain line which clashes with `a:g::K:R` in the J line. There are too few letters to be completely confident in any of the others. The most convincing (to me, at least) is a Q2 system, with a standard plain alphabet and a cipher alphabet beginning with the keyword `AEIOU`:
>
> ```
>   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
> J K  N  R    XYZA    B
>   KLMNPQRSTVWXYZAEIOUBCDFGHJ
>   VWXYZAEIOUBCDFGHJKLMNPQRST
> T  W YZ E O        K
> ```

> The keying is unusual - the key letter is aligned with plain `z` instead of plain `a`. A Q2 would normally key these as `K` and `V` instead of `J` and `T` but the system otherwise fits.

Comment: I'm so impressed by how many old cipher questions you've been able to come in and solve or sweep up after previous posters. Do your knowledge and solution strategies stem from professional work or are you a cipher hobbyist? :)

Comment: That's a funny question to answer. I do this for fun, but the way I got started was by failing to solve a nasty puzzle hidden in Noita and then having the thought "Weren't there, like, professional codebreakers at one time? Did they have technical literature, training manuals, that kind of thing?". And then I read everything William F Friedman had ever written. So I did learn from the pros, in a way.

Comment: But not a professional yourself, then - that's impressive. The ciphers used in the puzzles you've been solving are so wide and varied I had wondered if this was part of the day job for you. Well, I'm glad you're here to tidy up these unanswered/incomplete questions - cipher questions don't always get a lot of love around these parts! (Expertise is often required...)

Comment: Well, thank you! Feel free to ping me if you see something old I might like. :)

Answer (score 4):

I have not solved it, but I have noticed a pattern that may help future solvers. Or maybe it is just a dead end ?

> Consider that the first letter of each line is a key, and then you solve letter by letter.

Then you have

> (key=J) BAZRXKZN -> TONGLAND
> (key=T) WKOYEZ -> BRIDGE

If we use a

> Cesar's code, moving each letter to another one according to their place in the alphabet.

Then

> The distances from the cipher to the solution are quite regular, around +14 in the first word and around +5 in the second word:

Indeed:

> B->T : +18
> A->O : +14
> Z->N : +14
> R->G : +15
> X->L : +14
> K->A:+16
> Z->N : +14
> N->D:+16

And:

> W->B : +5
> K->R : +7
> O->I : +20 (?!)
> Y->D : +5
> E->G : +2
> Z->E:+5

The irregularities I cannot explain.

Comment: B->T should be +18 rather than +12 should it not?

Comment: The oscillation can be explained if it is not Cesar's but a keyword cipher.